# Clion and OpenMP

Tags: c, openmp, clion

I am learning parallel computing and have started my journey with OpenMP and C.

I have been configuring Clion, yet no luck.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
    #pragma omp parallel
{ 
   int n = omp_get_num_threads();
   int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    printf("There are %d threads. Hello from thread %d\n", n, tid);
};

/*end of parallel section */
printf("Hello from the master thread\n");
```

}

But i am getting this error:

In function `main':
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/Parallelexamples/main.c:6: undefined reference to`omp_get_num_threads'
C:/Users/John/CLionProjects/Parallelexamples/main.c:7: undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [Parallelexamples.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Parallelexamples.dir\build.make:95: recipe for target 'Parallelexamples.exe' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Parallelexamples.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Parallelexamples.dir/all' failed
Makefile:82: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2

I have followed instructions and made my CMakeListtxt files like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(Parallelexamples)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu11 -fopenmp")


set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)
add_executable(Parallelexamples ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Have i missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, since you are using CMake, take advantage of the `FindOpenMP` macro: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindOpenMP.html

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(Parallelexamples)
```

Secondly, it appears you aren't linking to the OpenMP runtime library. Not only must you pass the `openmp` compilation flags, you must also pass the correct linker flag(s):

```
set_target_properties(Parallelexamples LINK_FLAGS "${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

And just as a sidenote, if you are really programming with C not C++, you won't need `CXX_FLAGS` you can just use `C_FLAGS`

Answer (score 1):

In modern CMake, you should use [OpenMP's imported targets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindOpenMP.html).

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(Parallelexamples LANGUAGES C)

find_project(OpenMP REQUIRED)

add_executable(Parallelexamples main.c)
target_link_libraries(Parallelexamples PRIVATE OpenMP::OpenMP_C)
```